# flex 3 navigateToURL

Tags: apache-flex, navigatetourl

im using the navigateToUrl class to allow users to download some content - this works fine in Firefox however in IE a new blank page is opened with no content along with the download window (which is all i want showing up) any fixes for this ? cheers

Comment: Can you point to an example? Does the same site get opened in both browsers? What does the IE URL show?

Comment: THE url opened is the location on my server of the item im allowing users to download

Comment: Nah - I meant, does IT open the site you want at all or is it maybe IE that blocks popups or anything like that?

Comment: cheers sorted this by just using _self when opening the address - cheers

Answer (score 3):

in navigateToURL keep the second parameter "_self"...
example:
navigateToURL(url,"_self");

if you want to show your your file in a window then you will have to use iframe.

hope this will solve your problem.